# Can't pass data through states with same controller Ionic 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a value in page One, after tapping a button I wanna go to page Two and show that value in the screen. Both pages share the same controller, however I found that another scope is created when I change page.

Here is my code:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
})
.state('app.one', {
  url: "/one",
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('app.two', {
  url: "/two",
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/facts.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    }
  }
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/one");
})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.save = function(){
   $scope.var = "foo";
 }
});
```

First page just has a button that executes $scope.save, second page has this expression {{var}}
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Zgluis/pen/mOLNyr?editors=1111)

I suppose i have a misconception of something... Thanks!

Comment: Best solution would be to pass the variable as a stateparam, but you can also change $scope.var to $rootScope.var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Move the logic to a service.
2. Use a parent state with one controller for both states.
3. Pass the value as a parameter to the state.

Example #1:

```js
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="var"/> <a ui-sref="one">One</a> <a ui-sref="two">Two</a>',
        controller: function($scope, myService) {
          $scope.var = myService.getVar();
          $scope.$watch('var', myService.setVar);
        }
      })
      .state('one', {
        url: '/one',
        controller: function($scope, myService) {
          $scope.var = myService.getVar();
        },
        template: '{{var}} <a ui-sref="home">Back</a>'
      })
      .state('two', {
        url: '/two',
        controller: function($scope, myService) {
          $scope.var = myService.getVar();
        },
        template: '{{var}} <a ui-sref="home">Back</a>'
      });
  })
  .service('myService', function() {
    var self = this;
    this.getVar = function() {
      return self.var;
    }
    this.setVar = function(v) {
      self.var = v;
    }
    return this;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ui-view/>
</div>
```

Example #2:

```js
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/one');
    $stateProvider.state('parent', {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'appCtrl',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
      })
      .state('parent.one', {
        url: '/one',
        template: '<div>One: {{var}}</div> <a ui-sref="parent.two">Two</a>'
      })
      .state('parent.two', {
        url: '/two',
        template: '<div>Two: {{var}}</div> <a ui-sref="parent.one">One</a>'
      });
  })
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.var = 'MyVar'
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ui-view/>
</div>
```

Example #3:

```js
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.var = 'MyVar';
        },
        template: '<a ui-sref="one({var: var})">One</a> <a ui-sref="two({var: var})">Two</a>'
      })
      .state('one', {
        url: '/one',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
          $scope.var = $stateParams.var;
        },
        params: {
          var: null
        },
        template: '<div>One: {{var}}</div> <a ui-sref="home">Back</a>'
      })
      .state('two', {
        url: '/two',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
          $scope.var = $stateParams.var;
        },
        params: {
          var: null
        },
        template: '<div>Two: {{var}}</div> <a ui-sref="home">Back</a>'
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ui-view/>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot, since the begining I was trying to do the example #2, I saw yours and it is almost the same as mine, except because I was especifiying the controller in every state inside the .config, I removed those lines and now everything works, I don't understand why, please check my codepen and if you know the answer share it please, thanks!

Comment: Very simple. You call `$state.go(...)` before assigning the var value. This is like calling `return` and then expecting execution to continue in that function.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize $stateParams that have the object {var: $scope.var}

$state.go('app.two', {var: $scope.var});

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.one', {
      url: "/one",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.two', {
      url: "/two/:var",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html",
          controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/one");

})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$state, $stateParams) {
  $scope.platform = ionic.Platform.platform();
  
  $scope.save = function(){
    $scope.var = "foo";
    $state.go('app.two', {var: $scope.var});
  }
  
  $scope.var = $stateParams.var;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="one">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="save()">Next</a>
        Click to save a value in "$scope.var"
    </p>{{var}}
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="two">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p> Here should be the value of var -> {{var}}  </p>
       
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  

  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-stable" ng-class="{'tabs-positive': platform == 'android', 'tabs-icon-top': platform != 'android'}">
      <ion-tab title="one" ng-attr-icon="{{ platform != 'android' ? 'ion-home' : undefined}}" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </script> 

  <script>
    ionic && ionic.Platform && ionic.Platform.setPlatform("android");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```